An error occurs while trying to modify IdentityUsers Many-to-Many relationship
I'm trying to create a project to familiarize myself better and I have this ApplicationUser class:
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }
    public string? LastName { get; set; }
    public string? University { get; set; } 
    public string? CourseOfStudy { get; set; } 
    public int? GraduationYear { get; set; }
    public string? Bio { get; set; } 
    public string? LinkedInUrl { get; set; }
    public string? GitHubUrl { get; set; }
    public string? Skills { get; set; }
    public string? PortfolioUrl { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; } = new List<Category>();
}

Which should have a many to many relationship with the category:
public class Category
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
}

I have defined two contexts, one is for the application:
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Update> Updates { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}

The second one handles identity and roles:
public class AuthDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public AuthDbContext() {}

    public AuthDbContext(DbContextOptions<AuthDbContext> options) : base(options) 
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        var userRoleId = "298f9218-3e3a-4b21-9198-3cf08a40f191";
        var organizerRoleId = "5a0f7a7e-c62f-49db-bc0f-9b0061917e77";
        var adminRoleId = "a84035d4-a82f-4d10-a979-7a40f209256c";

        // Creater User and Admin Role
        var roles = new List<IdentityRole>
        {
            new IdentityRole
            {
                Id = userRoleId,
                Name = "User",
                NormalizedName = "User".ToUpper(),
                ConcurrencyStamp = userRoleId
            },
            new IdentityRole
            {
                Id = organizerRoleId,
                Name = "Organizer",
                NormalizedName = "Organizer".ToUpper(),
                ConcurrencyStamp = organizerRoleId
            },
            new IdentityRole
            {
                Id = adminRoleId,
                Name = "Admin",
                NormalizedName = "Admin".ToUpper(),
                ConcurrencyStamp = adminRoleId
            },
        };

        // Seed the roles
        builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasData(roles);

        var adminId = "66a83869-d054-4385-8f6f-2ad64ba78e3c";

        // Create an Admin
        var admin = new ApplicationUser
        {
            Id = adminId,
            UserName = "admin@teamfinder.com",
            Email = "admin@teamfinder.com",
            NormalizedEmail = "admin@teamfinder.com".ToUpper(),
            NormalizedUserName = "admin@teamfinder.com".ToUpper()
        };
        admin.PasswordHash = new PasswordHasher<ApplicationUser>().HashPassword(admin, "Admin@123");

        builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasData(admin);

        // Give roles to the Admin
        var adminRoles = new List<IdentityUserRole<string>>
        {
            new()
            {
                UserId = adminId,
                RoleId = userRoleId
            },
            new()
            {
                UserId = adminId,
                RoleId = adminRoleId
            }
        };

        builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().HasData(adminRoles);
    }

    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
}

The problem is when I try to edit my ApplicationUser entity and add categories:
[HttpPut]
[Route("users/edit/{id:Guid}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> EditUser([FromRoute] Guid id, [FromBody] EditUserRequestDto request)
{
    // Find the user by ID.
    var userToUpdate = await _userManager.Users.Include(x => x.Categories).FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id.ToString());
    if (userToUpdate == null)
    {
        return NotFound("User not found.");
    }

    // Check if the new email is already taken by another user.
    var existingUserByEmail = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(request.Email);
    if (existingUserByEmail != null && existingUserByEmail.Id != userToUpdate.Id)
    {
        return Conflict("Email already exists.");
    }

    userToUpdate.Email = request.Email;
    userToUpdate.UserName = request.UserName;
    userToUpdate.FirstName = request.FirstName;
    userToUpdate.LastName = request.LastName;
    userToUpdate.University = request.University;
    userToUpdate.CourseOfStudy = request.CourseOfStudy;
    userToUpdate.GraduationYear = request.GraduationYear;
    userToUpdate.Bio = request.Bio;
    userToUpdate.LinkedInUrl = request.LinkedInUrl;
    userToUpdate.GitHubUrl = request.GitHubUrl;
    userToUpdate.Skills = request.Skills;
    userToUpdate.PortfolioUrl = request.PortfolioUrl;

    if(request.Categories != null)
    {
        foreach(var categoryId in request.Categories)
        {
            var category = await _categoryRepository.GetAsync(categoryId);
            if(category != null)
            {
                userToUpdate.Categories.Add(category);
            }
        }
    }

    // Try updating the user.
    var updateResult = await _userManager.UpdateAsync(userToUpdate);
    if (!updateResult.Succeeded)
    {
        foreach (var error in updateResult.Errors)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", error.Description);
        }
        return ValidationProblem(ModelState);
    }

    return Ok("User updated successfully.");
}

It fails with an error

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_ApplicationUserCategory_ApplicationUsers_ApplicationUsersId". The conflict occurred in database "aspnet-53bc9b9d-9d6a-45d4-8429-2a2761773502", table "dbo.ApplicationUsers", column 'Id'.
The statement has been terminated.
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.b__208_0(Task`1 result)
at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__272_0(Object obj)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)


--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
ClientConnectionId:eb845a57-cc61-4b95-b4aa-683333ebfbd3
Error Number:547,State:0,Class:16

I tried running it with a debug and see if the category actually existed, and it did. While hovering across userToUpdate.Categories it was populated with a list of different categories.
Also checked if User is populated correctly and it seems to be fine with him also.
Another thing I did is commenting out the part where I update the user's categories and it works fine without it. Only when I'm adding the logic back the error occurs.

You can .ExcludeFromMigrations() so you can specify the same table in multiple contexts. But I would instead recommend defining the tables in a single IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser,IdentityRole,string> context.

@JeremyLakeman so I just move every DbSet from ApplicationDbContext to the AuthDbContext?

Since you have defined ApplicationUser : IdentityUser, you should be using IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser .... You could instead move those extra user details into a separate 1-1 table. Defining ApplicationUser in multiple contexts, with or without all its foreign keys, and getting those definitions the same seems annoying.

To fix the foreign key constraint error, define the many-to-many relationship in ApplicationDbContext.OnModelCreating using .HasMany().WithMany().UsingEntity() to configure the join table. When updating a user's categories, clear the user's Categories collection first to remove existing relationships, then add the new categories. This approach manages the relationships correctly and avoids the constraint violation.

@JalpaPanchal also where should I leave the DbSet of ApplicationUsers as I’ve realised I declared it twice (in ApplicationDbContext and AuthDbContext). Should it be only in ApplicationDbContext?

@rasky817 For clarity and to avoid conflicts, declare DbSet<ApplicationUser> in one context only.  AuthDbContext handles identity/authentication and should inherit from IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>. If ApplicationUser interacts with other domain entities (e.g., Category), consider moving DbSet<ApplicationUser> to ApplicationDbContext. This approach simplifies data access by centralizing domain operations in one context, especially if ApplicationUser is heavily involved in your domain logic.

@JalpaPanchal so if I move DbSet to ApplicationDbContext I should leave the tag of ApplicationUser in the IdentityDbContext? Or is it optional and I can put just AuthDbContext : IdentityDbContext?

To leave an update here I eventually solved the problem. It was because I had two separate contexts and it was just over complicating things. I read about some people who think that Authentification should be separate from Authentification logic, and some people who think that unifying is not a problem.
In ApplicatonDbContext I put the user set and extended it from IdentityDbContext and then in Models I created SeedData, which seeds all the user and user roles data on startup, from the Program.cs. Thanks for help!

You can post your solution as an answer it will help other in the future if they face same same issue.
